# Unable to start receiver com.google.android.finsky.instantapps.PhenotypeUpdateReceiver: java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-console

I have released my game to play console which is made using Unity. The Pre-launch report, reported the following crash issues during internal testing.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.google.android.finsky.instantapps.PhenotypeUpdateReceiver: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.phenotype.UPDATE cmp=com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.instantapps.PhenotypeUpdateService }: app is in background uid UidRecord{46dceb4 u0a249 TRNB bg:+10m41s432ms idle change:uncached procs:4 proclist:29801,29978,30388,30591, seq(0,0,0)}
```

AND

```
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
```

I am not sure, where exactly the error is and why?

[image]

Full trace for the first issue:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.android.vending:instant_app_installer, PID: 19323
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.google.android.finsky.instantapps.PhenotypeUpdateReceiver: android.app.BackgroundServiceStartNotAllowedException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.phenotype.UPDATE cmp=com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.instantapps.PhenotypeUpdateService }: app is in background uid UidRecord{64ad173 u0a135 TRNB bg:+13m22s373ms idle change:uncached procs:0 seq(0,0,0)}
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:4317)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:247)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2064)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
Caused by: android.app.BackgroundServiceStartNotAllowedException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.phenotype.UPDATE cmp=com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.instantapps.PhenotypeUpdateService }: app is in background uid UidRecord{64ad173 u0a135 TRNB bg:+13m22s373ms idle change:uncached procs:0 seq(0,0,0)}
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1861)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1817)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:774)
    at alj.a(PG:2)
    at alm.a(PG:3)
    at wnv.a(PG:2)
    at com.google.android.finsky.instantapps.PhenotypeUpdateReceiver.onReceive(PG:6)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:4308)
    ... 9 more
```

Full trace for the second issue:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-3-thread-1
Process: com.HefazSofts.AayaanTheRunner, PID: 19257
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.HefazSofts.AayaanTheRunner: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
    at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:375)
    at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser(PendingIntent.java:645)
    at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:632)
    at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.getPendingIntent(ForceStopRunnable.java:174)
    at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.isForceStopped(ForceStopRunnable.java:108)
    at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.run(ForceStopRunnable.java:86)
    at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run(SerialExecutor.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
```

Comment: I had the same issue still didn't find any solution, let me know if you got any information regarding this issue.